# Adding email to a package

Tags: email, email-template, package

I am trying to create an unmanaged package.  When I try to add it, I get:

```
 "My Personal Email Templates" and "Unfiled Public Email Templates" 
 cannot be added to a Package and are not shown in this list
```

When I go back to my email template, I see that I can only put my email template into the person email or unfiled public email template folder. So how do I package this email template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a folder and then moving the email template into that folder.

Comment: If you're able to solve a own question yourself, its not "wrong" to also accept it as answer. This way other community members can see the question is resolved.